# Http POST request get headers and body

Tags: php, post, curl, http-headers

I am currently using the below mentioned code to make http post request and it only returns body. I want the body and headers both. How I can I get body and headers both with file_get_content method or CURL?

```
    $sURL = "url";
$sPD = "data";
$aHTTP = array(
  'http' => 
    array(
    'method'  => 'POST', 
    'header'  => "Content-Type: application/atom+xml"
    'content' => $sPD
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($aHTTP);
$contents = file_get_contents($sURL, false, $context);

echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$context  = stream_context_create($aHTTP);
$stream   = fopen($sURL, 'r', false, $context);

$contents = stream_get_contents($stream);
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
```

You can also use the [HTTP Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php) if available.